# Invalid Code Signing Entitlements, error while submitting app to apple

Tags: ios, app-store, icloud, uploading

I am developing an app with iCloud enabled. While uploading the app to apple I got following error:

```
        Invalid Code Signing Entitlements. Your application bundle's 
signature contains code signing entitlements that are not supported by iOS. 

Specifically, key 
    `'com.apple.developer.icloud-container-identifiers' in Payload ------- not supported`
```

While surfing i also got some answer that disable iCloud,but I want to use iCloud feature for my app, so is there any other way to overcome this problem, please let me know.
Thanks in advance

Comment: might be you are assign you code sign with developer cer. create production cer and assign distribution cer for code sign.

Comment: Please let me know your deployment target.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like your provisioning profile is not configured to allow iCloud entitlements.  To do this, log into your dev account at http://developer.apple.com, go to the iOS Dev center, and Click the link on the right for "Certificates, Identifiers, & Profiles" under the iOS Developer Program on the right.  Find your app id in the Identifiers section, and click the edit button.  From there, make sure iCloud is enabled for both development and distribution.

[image: iOS Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles in the iOS Dev Center]

Also, make sure your app id prefix is not using wildcards.  You will not be able to use a wildcard prefix (com.example.*) when using any of the special entitlements, like iCloud, Push Notifications, etc.  Once you are sure that is set up with iCloud enabled, you will need to regenerate your provisioning profile.

Click the Provisioning Profiles on the left, and find you app store provisioning profile. Click the Edit button on the profile, select the app ID that now has iCloud enabled, and click the "Generate" button to generate a new provisioning profile.  Then download the provisioning profile and install it over top of the old profile.  Then re-build and sign the app and try re-submitting.

Comment: after all, go to Xcode `Preferences` > `View details...` and update user info. then, REBOOT Xcode! =)

Comment: Thanks Wottle ... your solution has been worked For me.

Comment: Glad it worked.  I had to do the same thing last year.

Comment: Nowadays, there's no separate checkboxes for development and deployment. You pick one of the other for the certificate. This process still works though.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution relevant to people re-signing their app:

If you have iCloud features enabled the provisioning profile will contain keys like `com.apple.developer.icloud-container-identifiers`. If you don't filter these keys out before you pass them to `codesign` they will end up inside the binary, which causes this error.

Comment: Someone upvoted this nearly four years later and I got the reputation notification. I have no idea what I was doing when I wrote this but glad to help.