# icloud entitlement not working in xamarin project - Invalid Code Signing Entitlements errors

Tags: xamarin.ios, icloud, signing, code-signing-entitlements

We have a feature in our iOS app where user need to pick up a document from his phone. We have used iCloud option as per Apple recommendation and enabled out profile with iCloud. The build is working fine with developer certificate but when we rebuild using distribution profile and try to upload to app store getting below error. We check entitlement.plist file and all values are as expected. Can you please help if you have faced similar issue. Snapshot of plist file below.

> ITMS-90046: "Invalid Code Signing Entitlements. Your application bundle's signature contains code signing entitlements that are not supported on iOS. Specifically, value 'Development' for key 'com.apple.developer.icloud-container-environment' in 'Payload/FastPass.iOS.app/FastPass.iOS' is not supported."
>
> ERROR ITMS-90045: "Invalid Code Signing Entitlements. Your application bundle's signature contains code signing entitlements that are not supported on iOS. Specifically, key 'com.apple.developer.icloud-container-development-container-identifiers' in 'Payload/FastPass.iOS.app/FastPass.iOS' is not supported."
>
> ERROR ITMS-90046: "Invalid Code Signing Entitlements. Your application bundle's signature contains code signing entitlements that are not supported on iOS. Specifically, value '*' for key 'com.apple.developer.icloud-services' in 'Payload/FastPass.iOS.app/FastPass.iOS' is not supported."
>
> ERROR ITMS-90211: "Invalid Code Signing Entitlements. The signature for your app bundle contains entitlement values that are not supported. For the com.apple.developer.ubiquity-kvstore-identifier entitlement, the value must start with the prefix provided by Apple in the provisioning profile, followed by characters that are uppercase or lowercase Roman letters [A-Z, a-z], the digits 0 through 9, dot ['.'], or hyphen ['-'], and not contain any wildcard characters. Specifically, value 'P6BTX25XKH.*' for the key 'com.apple.developer.ubiquity-kvstore-identifier' in 'Payload/FastPass.iOS.app/FastPass.iOS' is not supported."
>
> plist

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
          <key>com.apple.developer.icloud-container-environment</key>
          <string>Production</string>
          <key>application-identifier</key>
          <string>P6BTX25XKH.com.company.fastPass</string>
          <key>com.apple.developer.ubiquity-kvstore-identifier</key>
          <string>P6BTX25XKH.com.company.fastPass</string>
          <key>com.apple.developer.icloud-services</key>
          <array>
                   <string>CloudDocuments</string>
                   <string>CloudKit</string>
          </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: Is iCloud enabled for both development and distribution when you config you App identifies? Check the things [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25131570/invalid-code-signing-entitlements-error-while-submitting-app-to-apple).

Comment: Yes it is enable for both development and distribution.